# How do I compute \$V_{out}\$ in a MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet

Did not understand my lecture about MOSFETs. Specifically, how do I compute \$V_{out}\$ in the circuit below?

[image: circuit]

[image: characteristics]

Comment: I run a simulation using ltspice and i am getting 0V. I don't understand. [Here is my simulation.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EI1aE.png)

Comment: your voltage sources are only half connected, and backwards.  Connect their negative terminal to ground and their positive terminal to the node which you desire to supply with a positive voltage.  Also, the answer to the question will vary widely depending on the relative strength of the two MOSFETs, so to get the intended answer you will have to be sure the specific provided parameters are plugged into the simulation model properly.  Ideally you would do this both analytically and with the simulator and get comparable answers.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, i run the simulation again with the sources connected. Also i did the theoretical analysis of the circuit and the results were not comparable. I gave the results to my teacher and he said that if i am in the wrong direction he will repeat the lecture about mosfet.

Answer (score 1):

The following should provide enough material to allow you to unlose your lost lecture. If you just attempt to use it to plug in figures to solve a single assignment problem you will not gain much overall. The following is a [Potpourri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potpourri) and you will need to sort out which is relevant.

Best would be to "unlose" that lecture and/or get a proper understanding of the subject either from a textbook or a friend or a lecturer. Just having somebody help you plug numbers into equations like that isn't going to help you past the current assignment, at best.

[Here is a page](http://www.ece.msstate.edu/~reese/EE8273/lectures/tech_scale/tech_scale.pdf) that **MAY** help you with what you are doing.
 Slide 4 at the bottom of page 2 provides the information below. I have edited it somewhat to display better here and retain only what **seemed** relevant - see referred to page for extra information.

What this does is relate most of the parameters that you have in such a way that you should be able to plug the results into the diagram that you have.
 YOU have to decide if this satisfies hat you really need. You may need to think creatively to link some parameters as naming conventions seem slightly different.

- **Drain Current, MOS transistor, in Saturation,  Long Channel**

  - IDSAT
    = K’n
    /2  *  W/L *(VGS
    –VT 
    )
    2
    (1 +   λ*VDS
    )
  - K’
    n
    = µn
    Cox

---

Also of possible use are [These notes](http://www.erc.msstate.edu/mpl/education/classes/ee4253/pp38-thru-45.pdf)

Also [this annoying SCRIBD document - page 5 especially](http://www.scribd.com/doc/7348269/MOSFET-Parameters) **MAY** be of use

[image]

---

And this [Fairchild application note](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ms/MS/MS-556.pdf) gives a somewhat simplistic but possibly quite useful guide.

Including

The following calculations derive how Gate Length “W”
effects RON.

- ID = (µn
  COX) W/L [(VGS − VT) VDS − 1/2VDS^
  2
  ]

  Where:
  µn
  = Electron mobility, (the ease with which electrons drift
  in the material)
  COX = Oxide capacitance
  W  = Length of the gate (see Figure 1)
  L  = Width of the gate (see Figure 1)
  RON = On Resistance or resistance drain-to-source
  ID = Drain current

RON can be derived by taking the partial derivative of ID
over VDS where all other variables are considered constant.

- RON = 1/(µn
  COX W/L)(VCC − VIN − VT))

  Where:
  VDS = 0

Therefore:

- RON = 1/(µn
  COX W/L)(VGS − VT)

  Where
  VS = VIN and VG = VCC

Therefore (Equation 1):

- RON = 1/(µn
  COX W/L)(VCC − VIN − VT)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not an assignment. It is an unsolved exercise from the lecturer's presentation. I thought that i could ask something like this in order to see how things work and then try to understand it because if i just ask about mosfet everyone could just throw a link to a website.

Comment: Your circuit looks like a CMOS type circuit, so some reading on CMOS might help. From what I can tell, both M1 and M2 are on; calculating the on resistance (RON) for each as per Russell's answer will allow you to calculate Vout.

Comment: @gunkhuan - hopefully my "links to websites" were a bit more directed than usual. You'll note that the formulae that were discussed or derived in all the examples I gave were specific to you problem given the parameters you provided. | Now that you have explained your position, I suggest you wok through what I've posted and if it doesn't completely address what you want we can discuss further. I didn't try and plug the data in but it looked like a solution is possible from what I gave. | NEXT  you need to undersand why :-).

Answer (score 0):

Just to give an idea about how to read the circuit: there is a diode-connected pMOS, that works as an active load, and a nMOS with a fixed value at its gate, so the only degrees of freedom are the current flowing in the circuit and the VDS of the transistor (which are complementary so it's one degree of freedom).

So you have the same current over the two transistors, and you can equal the term with Cox...(with Vgs and Vds as parameters), fix Vgs2 at 1.8 and Vgs1 as 0.7 and obtain Vds.

**NOTE**: the values (Vt is the most evident example) seem to be exchanged between M1 and M2, since usually nMOS have the highest beta for the same form factor.

### Calculations

Current equation for long-channel MOS in linear region:
$$ I_{DS}=
\frac{\beta '_T W}{L}\left [ (V_{GS}-V_T)V_{DS}-\frac{1}{2}{V_{DS}}^2 \right ]$$

Current equation for saturated MOS:
$$ I_{DS} \simeq
\frac{\beta '_T W}{L}\left [ V_{GS}-V_{T} \right ]^2$$

Now you can substitute the values for nMOS and pMOS considering that \$I_{DS}\$ is the same:

$$\frac{\beta '_{Tn} W_n}{L_n}
\left [ (V_{GSn}-V_{Tn})V_{DSn}-\frac{1}{2}{V_{DSn}}^2\right ]=
\frac{\beta '_{Tp} W_p}{L_p}\left [ V_{GSp}-V_{Tp} \right ]^2$$

And putting in the numbers (considering that \$V_{DSp}=V_{GSp}\$):

$$\frac{100 \cdot 150}{2}
\left [ (1.8-0.7)V_{out}-\frac{1}{2}{V_{out}}^2\right ]=
\frac{50 \cdot 10}{2}
\left [ V_{out}-1.8+0.7 \right ]^2$$

Comment: Just for fun I solved the quadratic equation, but I arrive at \$V_{OUT}\$ = 2.32V, while \$V_{DD}\$ = 1.8V. I may have made a mistake...

Comment: Mmh I might have made a mistake, but I would expect a really low voltage, since the nMOS is much more conductive than the pMOS

Comment: Hm, I must stop doing this for fun :-(. Mathematica gives -9.99V and -0.00232V as results, but also here the results are outside of [0V, 1.8V]

Comment: I deleted my last comment just while you posted your reply, it seems. Deleted because I guess you're right after all. I can't see any other errors.

Comment: It does make a difference: the first product on the right hand side changes sign. With other terms equal this means that the value between square brackets changes, and so will the solution.

Comment: @stevenvh Stupid mistake: M1 is saturated, since Vds is necessarily bigger than Vgs-Vt. Deleting a lot of things